# How to return NA instead of numeric(0) when conditions do not return a result in R

Tags: r, na

I am doing a simple boolean condition on my data in R
Sometimes data does not exist in the

For example if this condition doesn't have a match, it will return numeric(0) rather than a value

```
item_size = data_size$size[data_size$Item == item_code]
```

How do I ensure an NA is returned rather than nothing at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your always expecting exactly one value, you could do this:

```
item_size <- c(data_size$size[data_size$Item == item_code], NA)[1]
```

Comment: Seems impressive. Can we have the times comparing yours and others methods

Answer (score 1):

Try this (since `if`-testing for zero-length items is fairly standard R parlance):

```
item_size = if( length( y <-data_size$size[data_size$Item == item_code] ) ){ 
                y} else { NA}
```

From context I'm actually wondering if this were intended:

```
item_size = if( length( y <-data_size$size[data_size$Item == item_code] ) ){ 
                length(y) } else { NA}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear on how it will be implimeted but if it is to be used as I think it will be you could put in a catch to test if the item number exists

```
# set up test data
Item <- c(1:4)
size <- c(11:14)

data_size <- as.data.frame(cbind(Item,size))

# wrap your command in an ifelse to see if the item being looked for is present,
# if it is then return the item code, if not return NA 

item_size <- ifelse(is.element(item_code,unique(data_size$Item))==TRUE,
                          data_size$size[data_size$Item == item_code],
                          NA)
```